# Apply formula to every other column in excel

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I want to apply the following formula to the D, F, H, .... all the way down about 500 columns, every other column.

```
Sub Repeat()
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'ASLs total'!C[-5]:C[-4],2,0)"
    Range("F3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F3:F1159")
    Range("F3:F1159").Select
End Sub
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: something like this: `Range("D3:H1159").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'ASLs total'!C[-5]:C[-4],2,0)"`?

Comment: Sorry- where does this apply the formula to every other column?

Comment: `Range("D3:H1159")` means that formula would be applied to `D3:H1159`. Change this range to suit

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But I dont want to manually type out 500 ranges, I want the macro to only do this formaula for every other column range.some kind of count +1

Comment: not sure why you should type out 500 ranges if you can do this one: `Range("D3:SF1159").FormulaR1C1=...` where `D3:SF1159` contains 500 columns. Or this one: `Range("D3:D1159").Resize(,500).FormulaR1C1=...`

Comment: I completely understand where you are coming form, but in my case it would be like Range("D3:D1159").FormulaR1C1=... Range("F3:F1159").FormulaR1C1=... Range("H:H1159").FormulaR1C1=... Notice how I skip E, G and every other range?

Comment: sorry, misunderstood your question, you want to skip every second column..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accomplish this via a for loop using the step function. Something like this:

```
Sub Repeat()
    For ColNum = 4 To 500 Step 2
        Range(Cells(3, ColNum), Cells(1159, ColNum)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'ASLs total'!C[-5]:C[-4],2,0)"
    Next ColNum
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks like its it, I wont check it off yet becuse I think the C[-5]:C[-4] are being weird. I tried to change it to A:B in the macro (as it works on the sheet) but i get a ?NAME error.

Comment: That was your formula... I just copied that part to show you how to do the part that you actually asked about - Skipping columns.... The problem would be, for example, for `column D` there is no `C[-5]`... But that was what you supplied....

Comment: If it's my formula I will figure it out, you solved the "every other column" predicimant.Thanks!!